# Getting Exception Index 1 requested, with a size of 1

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am getting exception while fetching data from database in my android project. I am trying to get value of `column index 1` from this line of code `String ques=c.getString(1);`

And this is the code where i am calling database class and trying to fetch database,

```
try{
c=db.getText(Integer.toString(subid));
    if(c==null)
        return;
    //if(c.getCount()> 0)
    //{
        //int max=c.getCount();
        //int min=0;

        Random rn = new Random();       
        int randomNum =  rn.nextInt(max-1) + rowid;
        c.moveToPosition(randomNum);

        String ques=c.getString(1);
        tv.setText(ques+" ");

        cans=c.getString(2);
        shuffleArray(ans);
        int[] a = new int[4];
        int j=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < ans.length; i++)
            {
              a[j]=ans[i];
              j++;
            }
         ans1=c.getString(a[0]);
         ans2=c.getString(a[1]);
         ans3=c.getString(a[2]);
         ans4=c.getString(a[3]);
         rb1.setText(ans1);
         rb2.setText(ans2);
         rb3.setText(ans3);
         rb4.setText(ans4);
        }

       catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage()+"exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Snap shot of my database content,

[image]

this is my database class,

```
public Cursor getText(String subId) throws SQLException //here it'll get all rows of subId=1 or whatever the value of subId
{
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_id, KEY_ques, KEY_correctans, KEY_wrongans1,KEY_wrongans2, KEY_wrongans3}, 
            KEY_subjectid + "=" +  " '" + subId + "' " , null,null,null, null,null);
    if (mCursor != null) 
    {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}
```

Please help me and hope my question is clear.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `I am getting exception while fetching data from database in my android project.`  you are getting super exception `Exception` ?? or any child `Exception`'s ?

Comment: Shiv, try `String ques = c.getString(0)` instead?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @Shiv When asking a question that contains "I am getting the exception ..." _always_ include a stacktrace :)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar CursorIndexOutOfBound: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: @PiotrChojnacki Can you please explain why ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int) Mind the "zeroBased". The first is Index "0".

Comment: @PiotrChojnacki I want to fetch column index 1 not 0

Comment: Have you verified that you're actually getting results and that the result set actually contains more than one column or do you just *assume* this should be the case?

Comment: @Shiv You obviously do not have a column at index 1, because your cursor is only 1 column wide. If you expect else, check your sql query.

Comment: 'c' basically contains just one column; while you are trying to access the second column (as indicated by getString(1)). since you've used getString(2) as well; Its obvious that you assume 'c' to have the result of multiple columns. But there is only one; which indicates some logical error in the way you are extracting data. 
If you can post the code preceding this and also be a bit more clear as to what exatly you are trying to acheive; it'd be a bit more helpful

Comment: what type of object is 'db' btw? and wt does the db.getText() method do exactly?

Comment: @MMss db is the object of my database class and have you seen i have edited my post.

Comment: I have Edited my post please see it again.

Comment: Everything seems proper unfortunately :-(... try using c.getColoumnCount() to confirm exactly how many columns you are getting in the result. and remove c.movetoposition(random) for now; use cr.movetofirst() instead and try

Comment: @MMss I am getting `6` column count while using this `c.getColumnCount()`

Comment: @MMss When I use c.movetofirst() instead of  c.movetoposition(randomNum) then the project is running without any exception but every time i am getting same question :(

Comment: check your logcat. at exactly which line are u getting the exception??
c.getString(1);?

Comment: ok i got it. i'll post a solution; if the project is wrking wdout exceptn now, it'll work for random questions as well

Answer (score 3):

You have an error:

```
Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
```

It says, that the size of your cursor is 1 and you know that indexing starts with 0. Therefore, if you write:

```
String ques = c.getString(1);
```

you try to get SECOND element, not the first one. If you want to get first element, you have to write:

```
String ques = c.getString(0);
```

Comment: But what if i want to get second element ?

Comment: @Shiv You don't have second element... error clearly states that size of your `Cursor` is 1, so it only has 1 element.

Comment: umm... u'll only get the second element if its there in the cursor. your cursor just has one element. how can u select the second element?
I think you need to go back in your code and change your query, so that u have more colomns

Comment: @PiotrChojnacki I have Edited my post please see it again.

Comment: @MMss I have Edited my post please see it again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove c.MovetoPosition(randomno);

Instead try this:

```
c.moveToFirst();
int rw_cnt=c.getCount();
int rndm = ((Math.random())*10000)%rw_cnt); //generates a random no btwn 1 and rw_cnt
for(int i=0;i<rndm;i++)  //move cursor rand times
c.moveToNext();
```

This definitely would be slower than c.moveToPostion(); but it wouldn't make much of a difference unless you have thousands of rows

Comment: And I dont want to generate random number from 1. I want to generate it between the value of variable `rowid` (which will be as minimum value) to `rw_cnt` (which will be as maximum value)

Comment: From my random number generator method when `rowid is 1` then its running properly but when `rowid is 51 or any other value` then getting this Exception `Index 50 requested, with a size of 50`. help :(

Comment: I assume u have rowid... so just:

int rndm=0;

while(rndm<rowid)

rndm = ((Math.random())*10000)%rw_cnt);